# Making a Turtle Object Look Look Further for Another Object

Tags: python, offset, turtle-graphics

In this simulation bears, fish, and plants randomly move across a grid to eat, breed, and die.  I have the simulation working fine one way so far.  What I am trying to do now is modify the Bear class' tryToMove method.  I want the bears to move more intelligently, like looking further out from its position to see if there are any fish in one direction.  What would be the best way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
from math import *
from turtle import *
from random import *
import turtle
import random
import math

def mainSimulation():
    numberOfBears = 5
    numberOfFish = 5
    numberOfPlants = 5
    worldLifeTime = 2500
    worldWidth = 30
    worldHeight = 25

    myworld = World(worldWidth,worldHeight,numberOfBears,numberOfFish)
    myworld.draw()
    myworld.getBearStarvePass()
    myworld.getBearBreedPass()
    myworld.setBearStarvePass(25)
    myworld.setBreedPass(3)
    myworld.getFishOvercrowdNum()
    myworld.getFishBreedPass()
    myworld.setFishOvercrowdNum(5)
    myworld.setFishBreedPass(2)

    for i in range(numberOfFish):
        newfish = Fish(myworld)
        x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
        y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        while not myworld.emptyLocation(x,y):
            x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
            y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        myworld.addThing(newfish,x,y)

    for i in range(numberOfBears):
        newbear = Bear(myworld)
        x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
        y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        while not myworld.emptyLocation(x,y):
            x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
            y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        myworld.addThing(newbear,x,y)

    for i in range(numberOfPlants):
        newplant = Plant()
        x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
        y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        while not myworld.emptyLocation(x,y):
            x = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxX())
            y = random.randrange(myworld.getMaxY())
        myworld.addThing(newplant,x,y)

    for i in range(worldLifeTime):
        myworld.liveALittle()
        myworld.showCounts()


    myworld.freezeWorld()
```

THIS IS THE WORLD CLASS

```
class World:
    def __init__(self,mx,my,bear,fish):
        self.maxX = mx
        self.maxY = my
        self.thingList = []
        self.grid = []
        self.bearCount = bear
        self.fishCount = fish
        self.fishOvercrowdNum = 0
        self.fishBreedNum =0
        self.bearStarvePass = 0
        self.bearBreedPass = 0

        for arow in range(self.maxY):
            row=[]
            for acol in range (self.maxX):
                row.append(None)
            self.grid.append(row)

        self.wturtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.wscreen = turtle.Screen()
        self.wscreen.setworldcoordinates(0,0,self.maxX-1,self.maxY-1)
        self.wscreen.addshape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Bear.gif")
        self.wscreen.addshape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Fish.gif")
        self.wscreen.addshape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Plant.gif")
        self.wturtle.hideturtle()

    def getBearStarvePass(self):
        return self.bearStarvePass

    def getBearBreedPass(self):
        return self.bearBreedPass

    def setBearStarvePass(self, newNum):
        self.bearStarvePass = newNum

    def setBreedPass(self, newNum):
        self.bearBreedPass = newNum

    def getFishOvercrowdNum(self):
        return self.fishOvercrowdNum

    def getFishBreedPass(self):
        return self.fishBreedNum

    def setFishOvercrowdNum(self, newNum):
        self.fishOvercrowdNum = newNum

    def setFishBreedPass(self, newNum):
        self.fishBreedNum = newNum

    def showCounts(self):
        bearCount = self.bearCount
        fishCount = self.fishCount
        self.wturtle.write("Bear: %d Fish: %d " % (bearCount, fishCount), move = False)

    def getNumBears(self):
        return self.bearCount

    def getNumFish(self):
        return self.fishCount

    def incBear(self):
        self.bearCount = self.bearCount + 1

    def incFish(self):
        self.fishCount = self.fishCount + 1

    def decBear(self):
        self.bearCount = self.bearCount - 1

    def decFish(self):
        self.fishCount = self.fishCount - 1



    def draw(self):
        self.wscreen.tracer(0)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxX-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxY-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxX-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(self.maxY-1)
        self.wturtle.left(90)
        for i in range(self.maxY-1):
            self.wturtle.forward(self.maxX-1)
            self.wturtle.backward(self.maxX-1)
            self.wturtle.left(90)
            self.wturtle.forward(1)
            self.wturtle.right(90)
        self.wturtle.forward(1)
        self.wturtle.right(90)
        for i in range(self.maxX-2):
            self.wturtle.forward(self.maxY-1)
            self.wturtle.backward(self.maxY-1)
            self.wturtle.left(90)
            self.wturtle.forward(1)
            self.wturtle.right(90)
        self.wscreen.tracer(1)



    def freezeWorld(self):
        self.wscreen.exitonclick()

    def addThing(self,athing,x,y):
        a = 0
        athing.setX(x)
        athing.setY(y)
        self.grid[y][x] = athing
        athing.setWorld(self)
        self.thingList.append(athing)
        athing.appear()
        if isinstance(athing, Bear):
            self.bearCount = self.bearCount + 1
        elif isinstance(athing, Fish):
            self.fishCount = self.fishCount + 1

    def delThing (self, athing):
        athing.hide()
        self.grid[athing.getY()][athing.getX()] = None
        self.thingList.remove(athing)

    def moveThing(self,oldx,oldy,newx,newy):
        self.grid[newy][newx] = self.grid[oldy][oldx]
        self.grid[oldy][oldx] = None

    def getMaxX(self):
        return self.maxX

    def getMaxY(self):
        return self.maxY

    def liveALittle(self):
        if self.thingList != [ ]:
            athing = random.randrange(len(self.thingList))
            randomthing = self.thingList[athing]
            randomthing.liveALittle()

    def emptyLocation(self,x,y):
        if self.grid[y][x] == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def lookAtLocation(self,x,y):
        return self.grid[y][x]
```

This is the Bear Class

```
class Bear:
    def __init__(self, theWorld):
        self.turtle=turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.up()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.shape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Bear.gif")
        self.offsetList = [(-1,1) ,(0,1) ,(1,1),
                            (-1,0)        ,(1,0),
                            (-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1)]
        self.theWorld = theWorld
        self.bearStarvePass = self.theWorld.bearStarvePass
        self.bearBreedPass = self.theWorld.bearBreedPass

        self.xpos=0
        self.ypos=0
        self.world=None

        self.starveTick=0
        self.breedTick=0

    def setX(self, newx):
        self.xpos = newx

    def setY(self, newy):
        self.ypos = newy

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def setWorld(self, aworld):
        self.world = aworld

    def appear(self):
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def hide(self):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def move(self, newx, newy):
        self.world.moveThing(self.xpos, self.ypos, newx, newy)
        self.xpos = newx
        self.ypos = newy
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)


    def liveALittle(self):
        self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
        if self.breedTick >= self.bearBreedPass:
            self.tryToBreed()

        self.tryToEat()

        if self.starveTick == self.bearStarvePass:
            self.world.delThing(self)
        else:
            self.tryToMove()

    def tryToMove(self):
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
        randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx=self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty=self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and
                  0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY() ):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
            randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx=self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty=self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx,nexty):
            self.move(nextx,nexty)


    def tryToBreed(self):
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
        randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(self.offsetList))
            randomOffset = self.offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            childThing = Bear(self.theWorld)
            self.world.addThing(childThing, nextx, nexty)
            self.breedTick = 0



    def tryToEat(self):
        adjprey = []
        for offset in self.offsetList:
            newx = self.xpos + offset[0]
            newy = self.ypos + offset[1]
            if 0 <= newx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= newy < self.world.getMaxY():
                if (not self.world.emptyLocation(newx,newy)) and isinstance(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx,newy),Fish):
                    adjprey.append(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx,newy))

        if len(adjprey)>0:
            randomprey = adjprey[random.randrange(len(adjprey))]
            preyx = randomprey.getX()
            preyy = randomprey.getY()

            self.world.delThing(randomprey)
            self.move(preyx,preyy)
            self.starveTrick = 0

        else:
            self.starveTick = self.starveTick + 1
```

This is the CLass Fish

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, theworld):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.up()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.shape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Fish.gif")
        self.offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                            (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                            (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        self.theWorld = theworld
        self.overcrowd = self.theWorld.fishOvercrowdNum
        self.breed = self.theWorld.fishBreedNum

        self.xpos = 0
        self.ypos = 0
        self.world = None

        self.breedTick = 0

    def setX(self, newx):
        self.xpos  = newx

    def setY(self, newy):
        self.ypos = newy

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def setWorld(self, aworld):
        self.world = aworld

    def appear(self):
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def hide(self):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def move(self, newx, newy):
        self.world.moveThing(self.xpos, self.ypos, newx, newy)
        self.xpos = newx
        self.ypos = newy
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)

    def liveALittle(self):
        adjfish = 0
        for offset in self.offsetList:
            newx = self.xpos + offset[0]
            newy = self.ypos + offset[1]
            if 0 <= newx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= newy < self.world.getMaxY():
                if (not self.world.emptyLocation(newx, newy)) and isinstance(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx, newy), Fish):
                    adjfish = adjfish + 1

        if adjfish >= self.overcrowd:
            self.world.delThing(self)
        else:
            self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
            if self.breedTick >= self.breed:
                self.tryToBreed()

        self.tryToMove()

    def tryToBreed(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                      (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                      (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            childThing = Fish(self.theWorld)
            self.world.addThing(childThing, nextx, nexty)
            self.breedTick = 0

    def tryToMove(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                  (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                  (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
        nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]
        while not(0 <= nextx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= nexty < self.world.getMaxY()):
            randomOffsetIndex = random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset = offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx = self.xpos + randomOffset[0]
            nexty = self.ypos + randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx, nexty):
            self.move(nextx, nexty)
```

This is the Class Plant

```
class Plant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        self.turtle.up()
        self.turtle.hideturtle()
        self.turtle.shape("E:/Python/Lib/idlelib/Plant.gif")

        self.xpos = 0
        self.ypos = 0
        self.world = None

        self.breedTick = 0

#accessor and mutators

    def setX(self, newx):
        self.xpos = newx

    def setY(self, newy):
        self.ypos = newy

    def getX(self):
        return self.xpos

    def getY(self):
        return self.ypos

    def setWorld(self, aworld):
        self.world = aworld

    def appear(self):
        self.turtle.goto(self.xpos, self.ypos)
        self.turtle.showturtle()

    def hide(self):
        self.turtle.hideturtle()

    def tryToBreed(self):
        offsetList=[(-1,1),(0,1),(1,1),
                    (-1,0)      ,(1,0),
                    (-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-1)]
        randomOffsetIndex=random.randrange(len(offsetList))
        randomOffset=offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
        nextx=self.xpos+randomOffset[0]
        nexty=self.ypos+randomOffset[1]
        while not(0<=nextx<self.world.getMaxX()and
                  0<=nexty<self.world.getMaxY() ):
            randomOffsetIndex=random.randrange(len(offsetList))
            randomOffset=offsetList[randomOffsetIndex]
            nextx=self.xpos+randomOffset[0]
            nexty=self.ypos+randomOffset[1]

        if self.world.emptyLocation(nextx,nexty):
            childThing=Plant()
            self.world.addThing(childThing,nextx,nexty)
            self.breedTick=0

    def liveALittle(self):
        offsetList = [(-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1),
                      (-1, 0)        , (1, 0),
                      (-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1)]
        self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
        if self.breedTick >= 5:
            self.tryToBreed()
        adjplant = 0
        for offset in offsetList:
            newx = self.xpos + offset[0]
            newy = self.ypos + offset[1]
            if 0 <= newx < self.world.getMaxX() and 0 <= newy < self.world.getMaxY():
               if (not self.world.emptyLocation(newx, newy)) and isinstance(self.world.lookAtLocation(newx, newy), Plant):
                       adjplant = adjplant + 1

        if adjplant >= 2:
            self.world.delThing(self)
        else:
            self.breedTick = self.breedTick + 1
            if self.breedTick >= 12:
                self.tryToBreed()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainSimulation()
```

Comment: do you get error message ? if not then you are on wrong portal.

Comment: No I do not get a error message.